# Convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd with date type Power Bi/Query

Tags: pandas, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have an issue in Power BI to convert a date dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd but keep the type as a date, because I convert it into text and I had this format but the type is text may someone have an idea how to solve it. Thanks

```
    #"Type modifié2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(AjouterCode,{{"DATECREATION", type date}}),
  
    AjouterDateFormatee = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié2" , "DATE_CREATION",
        each Date.ToText([DATECREATION], "yyyy-MM-dd")
    ),
#"Type modifié4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    #"Colonnes supprimées",
    {
        {"DATE_CREATION", type date}})
```

I've tried this :

```
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Type modifié4",{{"DATE_CREATION", type date}}, "en-GB")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date has been correctly parsed in PQ, you don't need to do anything further there. Leave it as a date type and change how that date is displayed in Power BI.

Select your date column in the data pane:

[image]

On the ribbon, select Column Tools and manually type in the format as shown. When shown in a visual, the data type will still be date but the format will be your typed format.
[image]

Comment: Yeah that's work. Thanks for your help. I discovered that when I export the data by DAX studio to CSV file the type of date changed into date time

Answer (score 2):

Davide showed the right answer. If at the front end you want to format a date into the correct format, use a formatting string. That's the only way to do it whilst keeping the data type of a column as a date.

In case you want to format a date as text you can use the Date.ToText function.

```
Date.ToText( #date( 2023, 12, 31), [Format = "yyyy-MM-dd] )
```

The above line should get you started. And for more custom formats you can find all here: https://powerquery.how/date-totext/

Cheers, Rick

---

Master Power Query M? -> https://powerquery.how

Comment: Thank you for your reply yeah effectively David's answer works but still have the issue while I export data by DAX studio into cvs file